# Laravel Newbie: model Class Not Found in routes.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Creating my first model with Laravel and its stored at app/models/Login.php.  It is:

```
class Login extends Eloquent {
  public $timestamps = false;
}
```

In a Route in `routes.php` I am getting a `Class 'Login' not found` on the line `$logins = Login::all();`

I have run `composer dump-auto` in the root of the application (above `app`) and confirmed that the composer.json file contains `"app/models",` in the `autoload` `classmap`.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Adding the Route (never mind that it doesn't actually use num yet):

```
Route::get('/logins/last/{num}', function($num)
{
$logins = Login::all();
return View::make ('logins.last.index')
  ->with('logins', $logins)
  ->with('num', $num);
})->where('num', '[0-9]+'
);
```

Comment: Did you add the table `protected $table = 'login';`?

Comment: I hadn't, but I did now.  I think it would need to find the class before that problem would have been the issue.

Comment: What about other classes ( `User` class for example) ?

Comment: Ding Ding! OK, User (in app/models) worked.  Because, unlike my model, it actually is encapsulated in `<?php ... ?>`  Embarrasing, but done.  Thanks, Razor!  Put it in as answer so I can select it?

Comment: I wanted to say in my previous comment, but I found it obvious ^^.

Comment: Ridiculously red-in-the-face obvious.  :/  Thanks, Razor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap you code with `<?php and ?>` tags, which tell PHP to start and stop interpreting the code.